# Why simplexml set NULL to field if in xml it is empty?

Tags: java, xml, string, null, simple-framework

Considering this code:

```
public class Param {

    @Text(required = false)
    protected String param;

    public String getValue() {
        return param;
    }
}
```

And I have this xml:

```
<item key="Key"></item>
```

After parsing this xml `getValue()` returns me null instead of empty string.

Why is this Behaviour?

Comment: Because it is null, Space means that string is initialized and have value in to as space ACII code is 127

Comment: Yes, but why it is not empty String (not space)? Annotation has attribute empty, by default it has value "", not null, it has to define default value for this field.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior refer that it found have an empty (not space) value. So the String bind to that not even initialize (will not occupies memory).

as `String a="";` is a initialized variable and it have memory allocated on low level. Otherwise there is no need of initialization if it is set empty. It can be costly for enterprise applications for class objects.

**MORE**

About string is a char array and each char is assosiated with [ASCII](http://ascii.cl/) value

Test it

```
String a="";
System.out.println(a));
```

output:

```
//[B@459bdb65
```

and

```
String a;
System.out.println(a));
```

output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable a might not have been initialized
```

Where about char

```
char a='A';
System.out.println((int)a);
```

output:

```
65
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK the behaviour you're experiencing is the expected with your code.

If you want to make empty element be returned as empty string instead of null, the best way is to build a `Converter`.

Another way is via annotation and use the behaviour, you can annotate it as required:

```
@Element(name = "PARAM", required = true)
private String param;
```

The `required = true` will throw an exception if drop is empty. You can use this if an empty drop is not allowed.

A second way is set `required = false` so will be deserialized to null if it's empty:

```
boolean isEmpty = ( a.getParam() == null );
```